# How to have different onAction callbacks for multiple copies of the same scene?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I am loading a Reality Composer scene, that contains a tappable box, and then creating two copies of it as follows:

```
func loadScene() {

    guard let sceneTemplate = try? HelloComposer.loadMainScene() 
    else { return }

    let helloScene1 = sceneTemplate.clone(recursive: true)
    let helloScene2 = sceneTemplate.clone(recursive: true)

    helloScene1.children.first?.position = simd_make_float3(0, 0.5, 0)

    helloScene1.actions.tapTheBox.onAction = { entity in
        guard let entity = entity else { return }
        print("top box tapped")
    }

    helloScene2.actions.tapTheBox.onAction = { entity in
        guard let entity = entity else { return }
        print("bottom box tapped")
    }

    arView.scene.anchors.append(helloScene1)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(helloScene2)
}
```

What happens is that upon tapping the top box (helloScene1) both "top box tapped" and "bottom box tapped" fire, whereas upon tapping the bottom box (helloScene2) nothing happens. Why?

Since both callbacks fire at the same time I assume somehow the tappable object is still in the same place, even though they're displayed properly at different positions.

I tried moving the entire scene instead of its child specifically, but it seems changing the scene's .position parameter does not have any effect.